# How to store user data in a Python class?

Tags: python, class, input, attributes

I'm trying to figure out how to store separate user data in a python class. Everywhere i look they( tutorials, internet) fill it in . I've played around for a few days now, and cant get it to work. This is as far as i can get. Thanks for any help, and hope some people get a good laugh at how simple this probably is.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age


name = input('please enter name: ')
email = input('please enter email: ')
age = input('please enter age: ')

user1 = User(name=name, email=email, age=age)
user2 = User(name=name, email=email, age=age)

print(f'Hello {user1.name}')
print(f'Hello {user2.name}')
```

Comment: Please check if your indentation is correct and [edit] your question to fix it! To quickly answer your question: It's not `User()` but `User(name, email, age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age

newName = input("What is your name: ")
newEmail = input("What is your email: ")
newAge = input("What is your age: ")

newUser = User(name=newName, email=newEmail, age=newAge)

print("Name is:", newUser.name, "age is", newUser.age, "email is", newUser.email) # Example on how to get values
```

It appears as though your indenting was a bit off.

**EDIT** Noted your comment about Stackoverflow requiring you to indent.  What I generally do is paste my code into stackoverflow via my editor of choice.  Then I select the code section, hold down `CONTROL` and hit the `K` key.  This then adds the appropriate indentation that Stackoverflow is looking for without causing me to manually add the indentation.

Comment: Mark your comment has helped a lot, and thank you. I did get my code to work, but i still cant just print the User. I have to refer to which value i want. I like the variable = input('type your text here'). It's pretty clean and helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age


print('please enter name: ')
name = input()
print('please enter email: ')
email = input()
print('please enter age: ')
age = input()


User(name,email,age)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you need to give the arguments `name`, `email` and `age` during the creation of the `User` object:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age

u = User('Bilbo', 'beutlin@hobbit.com', 122)
```

With this you can create the `User`-Object with your user input:

```py
print('please enter name: ')
name = input()
print('please enter email: ')
email = input()
print('please enter age: ')
age = input()

u = User(name, email, age)
```

BTW: Take care of the indention level. Every line after `self.age = age` must be one indent-level above.